# Center an element (Absolute) on the click

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, when I click on my screen, i want display a circle (centered verticaly and  horizontaly) where I click.

My poblem is that I get all the time the corner top left of my element.

Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DLeQuK0IKxHwUM1sWk0T

I have tried with

```
margin-left:-50%
```

but without success.

**Edit: I got answers very quickly, thanks!**

The Answer is to add to my class:

```
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
display: block;
```

```js
// Code goes here

function printMousePos(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("body");
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  para.className = "circle";
  para.setAttribute("style", "position : absolute;left:" + event.clientX + "px;top:" + event.clientY + "px");

  element.appendChild(para);
  console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}

.circle {
  color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  Click Everywhere
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
display: block;
```

to .circle class

Comment: Endeed, that's working but the center is done on the bottom of my cursor and not the top of it. Have you an idea?

Comment: You can try to add an offset to the `top` and `left` values to make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Left, top of the `div` are in your cursor position. You need to move your circle for 50% left and top.

```
function printMousePos(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("body");
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  para.className = "circle";
  para.setAttribute("style", "transform:translate(-50%, -50%); position : absolute;left:"+event.clientX+"px;top:"+event.clientY+"px");

  element.appendChild(para);
  console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that is working. but the center is done on the bottom of my cursor and not the top of it. Have you an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a additional container and place it exactly on the click location and set it to 0 width and height.

Then you place the message container in it and use the css transform property to translate it half way back: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

```
<div class="container">
    <div calss="circle">
        Your text.
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .container{
        position:absolute;
        top: XXXpx;
        left: XXXpx;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: show;
    }
    .circle {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #aaa;
    }
</style>
```

No need for tricky JavaScript tricks.

You can also add a fixed offset to the box by adding:

```
.circle {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    top: <XOFFSET>px;
    left: <YOFFSET>px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hre is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SYx7fyULumu64iXANO9G?p=preview), but there is something i cantundersand. Why the delay is more than the radus?

```
// Code goes here

function printMousePos(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("body");
  var para1 = document.createElement("div");
  para1.className = "circle";
  para1.setAttribute("style", "position : absolute;left:" + (event.clientX-125) + "px;top:" + (event.clientY-140) + "px");
  element.appendChild(para1);
  var para2 = document.createElement("div");
  para2.className = "point";
  para2.setAttribute("style", "position : absolute;left:" + (event.clientX-20) + "px;top:" + (event.clientY-30) + "px");

  element.appendChild(para2);
  console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, that's right too but it's more complicated to dupicate this answer to other item with different width and height.

Answer (score 1):

As we know the total width of the element will be 240 we can take half of that off the x and y coords like so.

```js
function printMousePos(event) {
  var element = document.querySelector("body");
  var para = document.createElement("div");
  para.className = "circle";
  para.setAttribute("style", "position : absolute;left:" + (event.clientX - 120) + "px;top:" + (event.clientY - 120) + "px");

  element.appendChild(para);
  console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}

.circle {
  color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 20px blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
Click anywhere
```